# Get Facebook Wall Facebook C# SDK -> Nested JSON

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to get facebook wall but I am having issues with JSON Nested structure.

following is my code so far

```
var wall = (JsonObject)fb.Get("me/feed");
List<FBWall> myWall = new List<FBWall>();
foreach (var obj in (JsonArray)wall["data"])
{
    FBWall myWall = new Wall();
    myWall.Id = (string)(((JsonObject)obj)["id"]);

}
```

actual string in wall is coming something like this

```
{"data":[{"id":"576376893_10150590188751894","from":{"name":"Afnan Bashir","id":"576376893"},"story":"\"how are you man??? \" on Xain Ul-Abiddin's timeline."........ and so on
```

now I have got data but when i do (as it should come like this because main file contains other json arrays)

`(((JsonObject)obj)["from"])` I get `{"name":"Afnan Bashir","id":"576376893"}`

now how would you write in `foreach` to get everything without going to another `foreach`. I was thinking for some way may be with `Linq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always hard to cast an object like FbWall to the returned results of the Graph API.  As much as I like type safety and being able to see compile-time errors, it was too much of a pain in the butt to convert the dynamic data over to a type.

So I've become adjusted to using `dynamic` (if you're using 4.0).

If you're not using 4.0, then you can continue to use `wall["data][0]["from"][0]["name"]` to get at values of the object returned.

I really do love living around the warmth and snuggliness of type safety, and I kicked and screamed about having to live down this unknown and uncomfortable road.  It will be all right, just "bite the bullet" and "get 'er done".

Comment: `I kicked and screamed about having to live down this unknown and uncomfortable road. It will be all right, just "bite the bullet" and "get 'er done".` lolx

Comment: when i do `wall["data"][0]["from"]`I have error `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public class Post
{
    public string ID { get; set; }    
    public BaseUser From { get; set; }    
    public string Text { get; set; }    
    public ItemType Type { get; set; }    
    public string Picture { set; get; }    
    public string Link { set; get; }    
    public string CreatedTime { get; set; }    
    public string UpdatedTime { get; set; }
}

public class BaseUser
{
    public string ID { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public enum ItemType
{
    Story,
    Message
}
try
{
     List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
     dynamic p = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get(userID + "/feed");
     foreach (dynamic item in p.data)
     {
     try
     {
        Dictionary<string, object>.KeyCollection keys = item.Keys;        
        Post post = new Post();        
        if (keys.Contains<string>("story"))
        {
          post.Type = ItemType.Story;
          post.Text = item.story;
          post.Link = item.link;
          post.Picture = item.picture;
        }
        else if (keys.Contains<string>("message"))
        {
          post.Type = ItemType.Message;
          post.Text = item.message;
          //post.Link = user.Link;
          //post.Picture = item.picture;
        }
        keys = null;        
        post.ID = item.id;
        post.UpdatedTime = item.updated_time;
        post.CreatedTime = item.created_time;

        BaseUser baseUser = new BaseUser();

        dynamic from = item.from;
        baseUser.ID = from.id;
        baseUser.Name = from.name;
        post.From = baseUser;
        posts.Add(post);        
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {}
    }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {}
```